# How to go back to Home Activity from a specific activity without overriding back button

Tags: android, user-interface

I am new to Android . Here I have for activities A,B,C,D in which A is the Home Activity.It is in stack as A->B->C->D

When I press back from B or C it should go back just as normal. But if I press back from D it should go back to A and from A the app should exit

Comment: Why don't you want to override the back button?

Comment: @codeMagic I think there is no other option but to override back button

Comment: @Pragnani I agree, at least nothing that wouldn't be real hacky, if at all possible. That's why I don't know why the OP doesn't want to

Comment: The answer that was posted and then deleted was the most straight forward.

Comment: I deleted (and readded it) because the question explicitly states that he does not want to override onBackPressed()

Comment: Use this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/41910314/1252158

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could intercept onStop() and guessing if the activity is switching to C and launching A instead. But it would result in a hard to maintain mess and I do not recommend that.

However, if for some reason you still not want to override `onBackPressed` and you manage to guess that D is stopping because back was pressed (without overriding `onBackPressed()`, just start A activity from there with an Intent with [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) (call i.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) )

According to the doc:

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

So A will be brought back and B and C will be cleared.

Comment: Overriding back button is the option but he don't want to do that.

Comment: Thanks!...now I think there is no other way other than overriding back button...It is working now.Thanks again @fedepaol

Answer (score 0):

when you start your new activity finish the old activity for example if you want to start C from B :

```
Intent I = new Intent(B.this , C.class) ;
 startActivity (I);  
B.this.finish();
```

Comment: But he can't navigate back from C to B when he press back button

Comment: I want to navigate back to B from C...thanks for ur reply.Its working now