# How to skip one activity when returning back? (DeepLink case)

Tags: android, back-stack, deeplink

I have got a small problem in an Android app I am working on. My app has such logic:

```
MainActivity(Root) -> OneActivity -> TwoActivity -> MainActivity ->  ThreeActivity
```

When I press `Back` button I need move to `TwoActivity`

It is important that `TwoActivity` create `DeepLink URL` and `MainActivity` generate `Intent` of `ThreeActivity`.
My `MainActivity` has `android:launchMode="singleTop"` and I cant finish() it.
Min API is 16.

Can I solve it with [Back Stack and Task](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html)?

UPDATE:

In my `TwoActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setData(new Uri.Builder()
.scheme(SCHEMA)
.appendEncodedPath(packageName)
.appendEncodedPath(PATH_APP)
.appendEncodedPath(packageName)
.appendEncodedPath(deeplink)
.build());
startActivity(intent);
```

In my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

<data
    android:host="${applicationId}"
    android:scheme="android-app" />
</intent-filter>
```

**So intent in TwoActivity != intent MainMenu.**

Comment: this link may help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826483/go-back-to-specific-activity-from-stack

Answer (score 0):

well, when you start an activity it will be added on the backstack by default, and by extension when you call onBackPressed afterwards it remove the last activity from that backstack.

So if you want to start an activity without adding it to the backstack you do it like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY));
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but after process DeepLink Android generate Intent for MainActivity - no Flags, no Extras